# Can you have more than 1 jquery effect on a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-effects

I'm on a project for work that requires push notifications.
The functionality works fine but the project leader wants to add extra ui effects to the notifications.

To do this we are using jquery effects.

My situation:

- I have this push notification that has a square with a speech balloon next to it.
- They are in 1 div together which is hidden.
- If needed, the div will show with an effect.

What I would really like is that the block comes sliding down, and after 0.5 or 1 second the balloon will unfold or slide out.

Is this possible to do in one div or do I have to make 2 seperate divs?

Or maybe to describe it in a different way, can you set the effect on a div so it would only show a certain part of the div by setting sizes? (Show pixel 0 till pixel 150 or something.)

Thanks in advance :)

**Edit:**
Example image 
[image]

Comment: In order to help, could you provide a code sample of the current situation?

Comment: Can't you hide the container+box+balloon then show the container then animate the box, then the balloon?

Comment: Well there is no code yet. 
For now im just wondering if what I want is possible, I will give a screenshot of the full notification ^^

Comment: Thanks for editing, making the problem more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using single div also by animating the height of the div from 0 to required height. Apart from controlling the height you need to set certain styles also like `overflow:hidden` on the div so that the overflowing content is hidden inside the div.

Answer (score 5):

I only partially understood your question (visual aids would have been good :D), but what I got was that you either want queued effects:

http://api.jquery.com/queue/

or effects to occur in parallel:

[How can I get jquery to execute animations in exact parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811750/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-execute-animations-in-exact-parallel)

Hope that helps. Comment if I am off the mark!

Comment: Well I posted something for some visual aid ;)

Comment: To bad I cant accept multiple answers xD
Both very useful so I just took the one that posted it first ;)