# Multiple jQuery-Effects parallel at same time

Tags: jquery, position, jquery-animate, parallel-processing, fade

i´d like to fadeIn a submenu and chance the position at the same time.

Like the cool Coda-Tooltip (http://panic.com/coda/) over "download".

My code just do the fade this time:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#access').hover(function () {
        $(this).children('ul').fadeIn();
         $(this).children('ul')...position();

    }, function () {
        $(this).children('ul').fadeOut('slow');
        $(this).children('ul')...position();
    });
});
```

Thanks
Ingo

Now I do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#access').hover(function () {
    $(this).children('ul').stop().animate({opacity:1, paddingTop:'10px'}, 400);

}, function () {
    $(this).children('ul').stop().animate({opacity:0, paddingTop:'0px'}, 300);
});
```

});

Fadein and the padding works great. But not by fadeOut. What´s my mistake?

Comment: this answer for parallel animations http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811750/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-execute-animations-in-exact-parallel

Comment: check out example in my answer.. I have been using it and loved it alot.

Answer (score 2):

the best i can think of is to make use of **[jQuery swichClass](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/switchClass)** . It uses `animate` `implicitly`.

**check out this fiddle example :** http://jsfiddle.net/xyDwV/1/

**CSS:**

```
.before{
    background-color : red;
    height : 400px;
    width :200px;
    opacity : 1;
}
.after{
    background-color : blue;
    height : 200px;
    width : 400px;
    opacity : 0.5;
}
```

**jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#mydiv').hover(function () {
        $(this).switchClass('before','after',500);
    }, function () {
        $(this).switchClass('after','before',500);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

simply roll your own animation with animate(). and never forget to use `stop` to cancel the currently running animation first.

```
$(this).find('ul').stop().animate({opacity:1, top:'...', left:'...'});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot roman. I try something ... see my edited question, please.